# How can I validate the type of a template function argument at compile time

Tags: c++

I'm writing a class for communicating sensor data and I want to make it so that a user of the class can't use an incorrect data type for sending sensor data.

I want to set up my class sort of like this:

```
private:
    static const _sensor_bytes[] = {2, 4, ...};

public:
    enum sensor_name_t {
        SENSOR1 = 0,
        SENSOR2 = 1,
        ...
    };

    template<class T>
    void writeData(sensor_name_t sensor, T data){
        if _sensor_bytes[sensor] != sizeof(T){
            // Do not compile
        }
    }
```

So for example,

```
int data = 30;
writeData(SENSOR1, data); // This would not compile because _sensor_bytes[0] = 2 and sizeof(int) = 4
writeData(SENSOR2, data); // This would compile because _sensor_bytes[1] = 4 and sizeof(int) = 4
```

Am I going about this in the right way? And if so, how would I accomplish this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with function `void writeData(sensor_name_t sensor, T data)`, because value of `sensor` is known at runtime, so it can't by validated in compile-time and rise an error.

**Variant 1**

You can try to use `std::enable_if`, move `sensor` from function parameter to template parameter and use `constexpr` for `_sensor_bytes`. It requires C++11 support by compiler.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

class Test {
private:
    static constexpr int _sensor_bytes[] = {2, 4};

public:
    enum sensor_name_t {
        SENSOR1 = 0,
        SENSOR2 = 1
    };

    template<int sensor,
             class T,
             typename = typename std::enable_if<(sizeof(T) == _sensor_bytes[sensor])>::type >
    void writeData(T data) {
        // Use 'sensor' and 'data' here
        // ...
    }
};


int main()
{
    Test test;

    uint16_t data1;
    uint32_t data2;
    test.writeData<Test::SENSOR1>(data1);
    test.writeData<Test::SENSOR2>(data2);
    //test.writeData<Test::SENSOR2>(data1); // Will not compile
    //test.writeData<Test::SENSOR1>(data2); // Will not compile
    return 0;
}
```

**Variant 2**

If you still need **both** function parameters passed **in runtime**, then validation should be done also in runtime:

- Use `assert`
- throw exception
- return some error code

Answer (score 0):

Using size to check the data type may not be the best approach for the following reasons:

1. Different data types can have the same size, such as float and int.
2. Using a different datatype does not always imply that the value contained inside the variable is wrong. For example, in your case:

   int data = 30;
   writeData(SENSOR1, data); // This would not compile because _sensor_bytes[0] = 2 and sizeof(int) = 4

the value 30 can be stored in 2 bytes, so do you really want to throw a compilation error here? However, that is purely implementation specific.

One way you can validate the type of template function argument *at compile time* is by initializing a dummy variable. Below is an example:

```
enum sensor_name_t {
    SENSOR1 = 0,
    SENSOR2 = 1
};


int sensor1;
std::string sensor2;


template<class T>
void writeData(sensor_name_t sensor, T data){
    switch(sensor)
    {
    case SENSOR1:
    {
        int temp = data;   // you know that sensor1 is of type int
        // do your stuff
    }
        break;
    case SENSOR2:
    {
        std::string temp = data;   // you know that sensor2 is of type string
        // do your stuff
    }
    break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    sensor1 = 30;
    writeData(SENSOR1, sensor1);
    writeData(SENSOR2, sensor1);
}
```

The above code snippet generates the following compile time error:

> error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string'} requested

The above logic can be implemented in a more elegant way. You can get some idea [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#constraints)